# HTML link on image only shows below that image

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I want to put a link on an image. I did it on other pictures aswell and it works properly. Just on that image the link is only clickable below the actual picture.

here is my code:

HTML:

```
       <a href="admin.php">
                <img src="steak.png" alt="AdminSteak" class="wrapSteak">
            </a>
```

and CSS:

```
  .wrapSteak {
      position: relative;
      top: 15px;
      left: 45px;
      height: 50px;
      width: 25px;
    }
```

Anyone knows a solution why the link isn't directly on the image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the issue - what broswer are you using?

Comment: well i copied your code and replaced the image with a placeholder. i cant figure out what your problem might be. it just works like every other image with an <a> around it. but im sure you are trying to accomplish something with top, left in the css that i cant see from your code

Comment: Try `display:inline-block` on `a` … Might also make more sense to relative position the link itself, than the image inside of it.

Comment: Your issue due to the `position: relative;`. Try removing this then it will come inline.

Comment: Here is your picture.. and also a [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/fudct5sr/). As @misorude said, use `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

Assigned wrapSteak to the parent element `a` and make it as `inline-block`.

```css
.wrapSteak {
      position: relative;
      top: 15px;
      left: 45px;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 50px;
      width: 25px;
 }
```

```html
<a href="admin.php" class="wrapSteak">
  <img src="steak.png" alt="AdminSteak">
 </a>
```

This should work. making anchor tag `inline-block` contains the image tag and if you applying position relative on `image` tag leaves `anchor` tag to its original position and the only image will be moved.